# Hadoop 2.2.0 Web UI not showing Job Progress

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have installed Single node hadoop 2.2.0 from this [link](http://learninghadoopblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/hadoop-0-23-9-single-node-setup-on-ubuntu-13-04/). When i run a job from terminal, it works fine with output. Web UI's i used

```
 - Resource Manager : http://localhost:8088 
 - Namenode Daemon  : http://localhost:50070
```

But from Resource Manager's web UI(shown above) ***i can't see job progress*** like Submitted Jobs, Running Jobs, etc..

MY /etc/hosts file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       meitpict
```

My System has IP: 192.168.2.96(I tried by removing this ip but still it didn't worked)

The only host:port i mentioned is in core-site.xml and that is:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even i get these problems while executing Map - Reduce job.

Best what i did that while executing Map-Reduce job you will get link on the box from which you executed MapR job for checking the job progress something like below:

> `http://node1:19888/jobhistory/job/job_1409462238335_0002/mapreduce/app`

Here node1 is set to 192.168.56.101 in my hosts file entry and that is for NameNode box.

So at the time of your MapR job is running you can go to the UI link provided by MapR framework.

ANd when it gets opened then do not close and there you can find details about other jobs also, when they started and when they got finished etc.

So next time better to check your putty console output after submitting the MapR job, you will definitely see a link for the current job to check it status from the browser UI.

Answer (score 0):

In Hadoop 2.x this problem could be related to memory issues, you can see it in [MapReduce in Hadoop 2.2.0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231403/mapreduce-in-hadoop-2-2-0-not-working)